# Characterization of two sets

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am  interested in the following problem:

Let $n \in \mathbb{N} $ . We define the function $S_n: \mathbb{Z_n^*} \to \mathbb{Z_n} $
\begin{align} S_n(\bar a) := \bar 1  + \bar a + \bar a^2 + ...+ \bar a^{\left(ord_na\right)-1} \in \mathbb{Z_n} \end{align}
where $\mathbb{Z_n^*}$ are the invertible elements of $\mathbb{Z_n}$ and $ord_na$ the order of $a$(mod($n$)).

Some pretty obvious results are:

1. $S_n(\bar 1)$ = $\bar 1$  $\forall n \in \mathbb{N^*} $
2. $S_n(\overline {-1} )$ = $\bar 0$  $\forall n \in \mathbb{N^*} $
3. $S_n(\bar a) = \bar 0$  $\forall \bar a,n$ : $ \overline {1-a} \in \mathbb{Z_n} $ is invertible. That is to say $gcd(1-a,n)=1$.

That holds because $(1+a + a^2 + ... + a^{ord_n(a)-1})(1-a)=1-a^{ord_n(a)}\equiv 0$ $mod(n)$

4. $S_p(\bar a) = \bar 0 $  $\forall \bar a \in \mathbb{Z_p^*} - \{\bar 1 \} $, when $p$ is prime

To prove that, notice that $\mathbb{Z_p^*}=\{ \bar 1, \bar 2, ..., \overline{p-1} \}$, so $\overline{1-a} \in \mathbb{Z_p^*} $ $\forall \bar a \in \mathbb{Z_p^*} - \{\bar 1 \} $

5. If $\mathbb{Z_n^*}$ is cyclic (that is to say $n=2,4, p^m$ or $2p^m$ for some $p$ prime and $m$ natural) and $ord_n(a) = |\mathbb{Z_n^*} | =\phi (n) $, then $S_n(\bar a)=\bar 0 $

This is true because $S_n(\bar a) = \sum_{i=1}^{i=\phi(n)} \bar a ^ i = \sum_{\bar b \in \mathbb{Z_n^*}} \bar b = \bar 0 $ (if $\bar a \in \mathbb{Z_n^*}$ then $\overline {-a} \in \mathbb{Z_n^*}$ and $\bar a \neq \overline{-a}$ because  $\bar a$ invertible. So $\mathbb{Z_n^*}$ comes in pairs $\bar a$, $\overline{-a}$ )

6. $S_n(\bar a) \notin \mathbb{Z_n^*}$ $\forall \bar a \in \mathbb{Z_n^*} - \{\bar 1 \}$

For this, notice that, in the relation in 3. , if  $S_n(\bar a)$ is invertible, $1-a \equiv 0$ $mod(n)$

However, 4. doesn't generally hold if $p$ is not a prime. For example, $S_8(\bar 3) = \bar 4$. That is not to say that it *necessarily*  does not hold. For example, for $n=6$, $\mathbb{Z_p^*}=\{ \bar 1, \bar 5\}$ and $S_6(\bar 5) =\bar 0$ (See 2.) And there are not trivial examples as well, let's say $n=10$, where property 4. holds.

So, the first natural question is whether we can find a characterization for the sets 
\begin{align} A_n:=\{ \bar a \in \mathbb{Z_n^*} : S_n(\bar a) = \bar 0 \} \end{align}

Now, considering the $\amalg {\mathbb{Z_n} }$ as consisting of the elements $(\bar a, n)$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and  $\bar a \in \mathbb{Z_n}$, we continue defining the function  $S : \mathbb{N} \to \amalg {\mathbb{Z_n} } $ such as
\begin{align} S(n) = \left( \sum_{\bar a \in \mathbb{Z_n^*}} {S_n(\bar a)}, n \right)\end{align}
thinking of $S(n)$ as an element of $\mathbb{Z_n}$ when there is no danger of confusion.

Result 4. from above implies $S(p)= \bar 1$. If $p$ is not a prime this does not generally hold, $S(8) =\bar 3 $ and $S(9)= \bar 7 $. Interestingly, both of those (and many more for that matter) are invertible. However, this is not generally the case (!). For example $S(12)=\bar 3$

This bring us to a second question. Can we find (or know more about) the set 
\begin{align} A:= \{ n \in \mathbb{N} : S(n) \in \mathbb{Z_n^*} \}\end{align}

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There will not be any simple description of these sets, even in some simple cases.
For example, let $p > 3$ be prime, let $n = 9p$, and let $a = 4$.
The problem becomes characterizing the primes $p$ for which $4$ mod $p$ (or equivalently, $2$ mod $p$) has order divisible by $9$. If $p \equiv 1$ mod $9$ but $p \not\equiv 1$ mod $27$, this is the same as asking that $2$ is not a cube modulo $p$. But there is no *simple* description of this set. It is certainly equal to the set of primes (with the given congruence conditions) which do not split completely in the field

$$x^3 - 2.$$

However, since the splitting field of this polynomial is not abelian, there will not be any congruence conditions on $p$ which determine when this property holds (as follows from class field theory). So roughly, the answer to your problem even in the simple triple $(n,a) = (9p,4)$ does not admit a simple answer. Similarly, if $p \equiv 1$ mod $27$ and not $1$ mod $81$, the problem becomes one of determining when $2$ is a $9$th power modulo $p$ or not, and if $p \equiv 1$ mod $3^n$ and not $1$ mod $3^{n+1}$, it's a question of whether $2$ is a $3^{n-1}$th power or not. These  "characterizations" do not really admit a simple description, and are really just reformulations of the original question.